# What is a scalar Object in C++?

Tags: c++, types, theory

As far as I understand it fundamental types are Scalar and Arrays are aggregate but what about user defined types? By what criteria would I divide them into the two categories?

```
struct S { int i; int j };
class C { public: S s1_; S s2_ };
std::vector<int> V;
std::vector<int> *pV = &v;
```

Comment: I think you may want to clean up the spelling and syntax of your introductory paragraph, and possibly expanind on it a bit if you want useful answers

Comment: Do you mean "types" and "aggregate"?

Comment: @us2012: "Tapes and Arrogates" should be an indie college band.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

**Short version:** Types in C++ are:

- Object types: scalars, arrays, classes, unions
- Reference types
- Function types
- (Member types) [see below]
- `void`

---

**Long version**

- Object types

  - Scalars

    1. arithmetic (integral, float)
    2. pointers: `T *` for any type `T`
    3. enum
    4. pointer-to-member
    5. `nullptr_t`
  - Arrays: `T[]` or `T[N]` for any complete, non-reference type `T`
  - Classes: `class Foo` or `struct Bar`

    1. Trivial classes
    2. Aggregates
    3. POD classes
    4. (etc. etc.)
  - Unions: `union Zip`
- References types: `T &`, `T &&` for any object or free-function type `T`
- Function types

  - Free functions: `R foo(Arg1, Arg2, ...)`
  - Member functions: `R T::foo(Arg1, Arg2, ...)`
- `void`

Member types work like this. A member type is of the form `T::U`, but you can't have objects or variables of member type. You can only have member *pointers*. A member pointer has type `T::* U`, and it is a pointer-to-member-object if `U` is a (free) object type, and a pointer-to-member-function if `U` is a (free) function type.

All types are complete except `void`, unsized arrays and declared-but-not-defined classes and unions. All incomplete types except `void` can be completed.

All types can be `const`/`volatile` qualified.

The `<type_traits>` header provides trait classes to check for each of these type characteristics.

Comment: Your breakdown list about floating point values may be wrong, ex. floats and doubles are not scalar types. `Non-scalar types including floats, doubles, and vector types such as __m128, __m128i, __m128d are returned in XMM0` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2017

Answer (score 44):

I think this would be a more comprehensive answer:

[image]

original document:
http://howardhinnant.github.io/TypeHiearchy.pdf

**a scalar is a fundamental except it cannot be void, but it can be a pointer type, or an enum type.**

And **a fundamental has a keyword in the language**. it is easy to recognize when said like that.

Answer (score 8):

There is a series of library classes that used for test the type of variables.  [`std::is_scalar`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/is_scalar/) can be used to test if an object is a scalar.

> A *scalar type* is a type that has built-in functionality for the addition operator without overloads (arithmetic, pointer, member pointer, enum and `std::nullptr_t`).

Also a table from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/).

[image: C++ Type Categories]