# OpenMP atomic on a reference type?

Tags: c++, openmp, atomic, reference-type

The OpenMP standard (<= 4.0) says about `atomic`:

> `#pragma omp atomic [read | write | update | capture ] new-line`
>    `expression-stmt`
>
> where `expression-stmt` is an expression statement with one of the
>   following forms:
>   ...
>   If clause is update or not present:
>   `x++;`
>   ...
>   In the preceding expressions:
>    `x` and `v` (as applicable) are both l-value expressions with **scalar** type.
>   ...

So, when I interpret this correctly, the following short code snippet is illegal:

```
int main()
{
  int myCounter = 0;
  int& reference = myCounter;

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    #pragma omp atomic
    reference++; // Increment through reference.
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Reason: According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14822074/3740047), a reference (here `int& reference`) is not a scalar type. But the standard explicitly states that it must be one, in order to use `atomic`.

The code compiles with g++, without any warning (`-Wall -Wextra`).

My question is: Have I misunderstood the standard, or the concept of C++'s "reference type"? Or do most compilers compile this code, because otherwise the use of `atomic` is severely limited (basically no data on the heap could be the target of `atomic`, because you always need a reference or a dereferenced pointer)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A reference type is not a scalar type. However, this fact has no bearing on your question. The important fact is that an expression that evaluates a reference to a scalar type *is* an lvalue with scalar type. To be specific, the *variable* `reference` has type `int&` but the *expression* `reference` has type `int` and value category lvalue. So yes, your program is conforming.