# Assigning base class object to derived class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
    class Base{};
    class Derived: public Base{};

    int main()
    {
        Base B;
        Derived D;

        Base B1 = D;//OK
        Derived D1 = B;//error: conversion from ‘Base’ to non-scalar 
                       //type ‘Derived’ requested
        return 1;
    }
```

I know derived class has a is-a relationship with base class.

What stops the Derived D1 having values from B and remaining member variables(if any) with some garbage value?

Or

What does the error message

> conversion from ‘Base’ to non-scalar type ‘Derived’ requested Derived D1 = B;

say? What is a scalar type?

Comment: You might add the constructor `Derived(const Base&)` to provide the conversion

Comment: The "is-a" relationship only works in one direction.

Comment: Ok, But my question was , why not by default.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Garbage values.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, previous question was about copy assignment, and no one talks about initialization.

Comment: The derived to base conversion can be implicit. A derived class consists of a base class *suboject*. `Base B1 = D` means to initialize `B1` by copying the `Base` subobject from `D` into `B1`.

The base to derived conversion is not implicit. A `Base` class does not contain its derived class object, only the other way around. However, if you have a reference or pointer to a `Base` class, you can explicitly cast through `static_cast` if you know its dynamic type is a `Derived` class or `dynamic_cast` (if you aren't sure) to get the pointed-to (or referred-to) derived object.

Comment: As for what a scalar is, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821936/what-is-a-scalar-object-in-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement

```
Derived D1 = B;
```

is an initialization, not an assignment (even if it looks like an assignment).

It attempts to use the `Derived` copy constructor, but that copy constructor takes an argument `Derived const&`. And the `B` instance can't be automatically converted down to a full `Derived`.

If you really want a slice assignment – assigning only to the `Base` slice of `D1` – then you can explicitly use the `Base::operator=`:

```
Derived D1;
D1.Base::operator=( B );
```

Another way to express that:

```
Derived D1;
static_cast<Base&>( D1 ) = B;
```

But it smells bad. ;-)

---

Re

> **”** What is a scalar type?

That's the same word as in “scale”. A scalar type provides a single magnitude value, so that values of the type can be compared with `==` (and ideally also `<`). However, in C++ pointers and even member pointers are regarded as scalar types:

**C++11 §3.9/9** [basic.types]:

> **”** Arithmetic types (3.9.1), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer to member types (3.9.2), std::nullptr_t, and cv-qualified versions of these types (3.9.3) are collectively called *scalar types*.

Answer (score 0):

If `B`'s member variables are declared private, then that would stop `D1` from having `B`'s values.

As far as your second question, You can assign `Base B1 = D;` because the compiler knows `D` is a derived class from `B`. However, in `Derived D1 = B;`, the compiler has no indication of that relationship.

As far as to your question of what a scalar is, scalars are ints, chars, pointers, etc. They are different from structs and classes, which are user-defined types.