# Structs in C Error

Tags: c, struct

I don't understand why the following code doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <string.h>

#include <ctype.h>

#include <math.h>

struct data 

{

    int age;

    char name[20];

};


int main()
{
    struct data element[2];
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        element[j] = (struct data) malloc(sizeof(struct data));
        printf("Enter fav number%d? \n", j);
        scanf("d", &element[j].age);
        printf("Enter fav word? \n");
        scanf("s", &element[j].name);
    }
    printf("\nThis is what you entered:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        printf("%d. Fav number: %d\n", k, &element[k].age);
        printf("%d. Fav word: %s\n", k, &element[k].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error says:

```
beispiele.c: In function ‘main’:

beispiele.c:199:51: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

   element[j] = (struct data) malloc(sizeof(struct data));

                                                   ^
beispiele.c:201:3: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]

   scanf("d", &element[j].age);

   ^
beispiele.c:203:3: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]

   scanf("s", &element[j].name);

   ^
beispiele.c:208:3: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]

   printf("%d. Fav number: %d\n", k, &element[k].age);

   ^
beispiele.c:209:3: error: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 3 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Werror=format=]

   printf("%d. Fav word: %s\n", k, &element[k].name);

   ^

cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: `scanf` uses `%d` and `%s` to read integer and strings respectively. Also you don't have to pass `&string_variable` as parameter. You have to pass `string_variable` since that itself is a pointer

Comment: `element[i]` is a structure in automatic storage and it has therefore already memory allocated. Judging from the code, you don't want `malloc` here, just the two elements that are already there.

Comment: Please activate warnings, which should tell you which of the ´printf` and `scanf` arguments don't match the format specifiers.

Comment: @MOehm Warnings are actually activated as per "_cc1: all warnings being treated as errors_"

Comment: @CoolGuy: Yep, and the warnings are there. Sorry for that, was judging from the code only.

Comment: "I don't understand why the following code doesn't work:" - oh.. So let me get this straight... You type some garbage and expect that it will do what you imagined it will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. Format specifiers start with a `%` sign. So change

   ```
   scanf("d", &element[j].age);
   ```

   to

   ```
   scanf("%d", &element[j].age);
   ```

   and

   ```
   scanf("s", &element[j].name);
   ```

   to

   ```
   scanf("%s", element[j].name);
   ```

   Wondering why I removed the `&` from the above `scanf`? It is because array names gets converted to a pointer to its first element.
2. These

   ```
   printf("%d. Fav number: %d\n", k, &element[k].age);
   printf("%d. Fav word: %s\n", k, &element[k].name);
   ```

   should be

   ```
   printf("%d. Fav number: %d\n", k, element[k].age);
   printf("%d. Fav word: %s\n", k, element[k].name);
   ```

   because the `%d` in the `printf` expects the value(`int`) and not the address of the variable(`int*`). Similarly, `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char(*)[20]`
3. The cast here is completely wrong and should be removed:

   ```
   element[j] = (struct data) malloc(sizeof(struct data));
   ```

   This is done because `malloc` returns `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer type without casting.
4. 5. 6. etc See other answers.

Answer (score 4):

`element[j]` is not a pointer and is a member of the array so already it has memory allocated statically.

If you need to allocate memory then have array of pointers.

```
struct data *element[2];
```

Comment: This is not the only bug in the code, however.

Comment: @Lundin Yeah not the only one but the biggest one :)

Comment: Casting the result to a non-pointer type is a severe bug.

Comment: why use malloc at all?   Joe's answer is better.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah it depends on what OP wants. If OP just wants to try out dynamic allocation he might want `malloc()` I didn't suggest `malloc()` just showed how it can be used

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for using malloc (the array allocates all the memory).

Note, using `printf` does not require the address of the variable, so the `&` must be omitted before the variable. You do with `scanf`, as you must pass the address of the variable to which you want to write so that it can be modified (note the `%d` and `%s` in the scanf too). However, with the `char[20]`, you do not need the `&` as the array is a pointer to the begin of the sequence of 20 characters.

```
int main()
{
    struct data element[2];
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
    {
        printf("Enter fav number%d? \n", j);
        scanf("%d", &element[j].age);
        printf("Enter fav word? \n");
        scanf("%s", element[j].name);
    }
    printf("\nThis is what you entered:\n");
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        printf("%d. Fav number: %d\n", k, element[k].age);
        printf("%d. Fav word: %s\n", k, element[k].name);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting 3 types of errors:

1. `beispiele.c:199:51: error: conversion to non-scalar type requested`
   `element[j] = (struct data) malloc(sizeof(struct data));`

   Check the documentation for [malloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) - it returns a void pointer to the allocated memory, which you then try to cast to a struct. The struct is obviously not a pointer type, hence the error message.

   To be precise, the error message tells you that you're trying to cast to a type that is not [scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821936/what-is-a-scalar-object-in-c) (roughly and incorrectly speaking, that is not a "basic" language type). C-style cast is very permissive and would happily perform many casts, for example, a `long long *` to a `long long`, without even a warning.

   Keep in mind that you [should not cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the pointer you get from `malloc`.

   Also, [as others have pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202021/structs-in-c-error/32202094#32202094), this statement:

   `struct data element[2];`

   declares **and** automatically allocates the `element` variable. By calling `malloc`, you're asking the compiler to allocate it again, dynamically. If you're confused about memory allocation, take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793111/1614641).
2. `beispiele.c:201:3: error: too many arguments for format [-Werror=format-extra-args]`
   `scanf("d", &element[j].age);`

   Format strings used by [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) use format specifiers starting with the `%` symbol, which is missing in all your calls. In this specific call, your format string `"d"` contains 0 format specifiers, so `scanf` expects 0 variable addresses to store values in. But you provide 1 address, so the compiler complains for "too many arguments".

   Also, note that `scanf` needs a the address of a variable because arguments are [passed by value](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/72-passing-arguments-by-value/) - if it took the variable itself instead, it couldn't store the data to be accessible after the `scanf` call returned. By contrast, `printf` does not need to modify variables, so it takes variables rather than their addresses.
3. `^ beispiele.c:208:3: error: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’ [-Werror=format=]`
   `printf("%d. Fav number: %d\n", k, &element[k].age);`

   This error message is pretty self-explanatory. Refer to the previous point about `printf`'s arguments.

Answer (score 0):

malloc returns a pointer to the allocated data, not the actual data. You should not cast the result of malloc.

Fix the code accordingly:

```
 struct data* element[2];
 ...
 element[j] = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
 ...
 free(element[j]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`malloc` returns a pointer to allocated memory, but you cast the pointer to a `struct data`. This is what the compiler complains about

> error: conversion to non-scalar type requested

Furthermore, you don't need to allocate memory at all, because you already did so by

```
struct data element[2];
```

So, when you drop the malloc line, this error should be gone.