# The scalar type additionnal in C++

Tags: c++, c, types, definition, scalar

In C the scalar type are:

- floating_point (double float, ...)
- integral (int, char, long, ...)
- pointer
- enum

In C++ the scalar type added are just :

- integral (bool)
- nullprt_t
- member pointer (member object pointer and member function pointer)

There is just the three type scalar added to C++?

Comment: what are you missing from the list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a scalar Object in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821936/what-is-a-scalar-object-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ the scalar types are (6.7 Types)

> 9 Arithmetic types (6.7.1), enumeration types, pointer types,
>   pointer-to-member types (6.7.2), std::nullptr_t, and cv-qualified
>   (6.7.3) versions of these types are collectively called scalar types.

In C the scalar types are (6.2.5 Types)

> 21 Arithmetic types and pointer types are collectively called scalar
>   types.

Pay attention to that in C

> 11 There are three complex types, designated as float _Complex, double
>   _Complex, and long double _Complex. 43) (Complex types are a conditional feature 
>   that implementations need not support; see
>   6.10.8.3.) **The real floating and complex types are collectively called the 
>   floating types**

In C++ complex types are user-defined types that is they are defined as classes.

Also in C enumerations are included in the category of the arithmetic types while in C++ enumerations are not included in the category of arithmetic types.

And in C there is standard unsigned integer type `_Bool` while in C++ it is absent. On the other hand, in C++ there is the integral type `bool` that is absent in C.

Answer (score 3):

The complete list of scalar types in C++ according to the standard (quoting the latest draft):

> [basic.fundamental]
>
> There are five standard signed integer types : “signed char”, “short int”, “int”, “long int”, and “long long int”
>
> For each of the standard signed integer types, there exists a corresponding (but different) standard unsigned integer type
>
> Types bool, char, wchar_­t, char8_­t, char16_­t, char32_­t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types
>
> There are three floating-point types: float, double, and long double.
>
> Integral and floating-point types are collectively called arithmetic types.
>
> [basic.compound]
>
> pointers to non-static class members, which identify members of a given type within objects of a given class, [dcl.mptr]. Pointers to data members and pointers to member functions are collectively called pointer-to-member types.
>
> The type of a pointer to cv void or a pointer to an object type is called an object pointer type. The type of a pointer that can designate a function is called a function pointer type.
>
> [dcl.enum]
>
> The enumeration type declared with an enum-key of only enum is an unscoped enumeration, and its enumerators are unscoped enumerators.
>   The enum-keys enum class and enum struct are semantically equivalent; an enumeration type declared with one of these is a scoped enumeration, and its enumerators are scoped enumerators.
>
> [basic.types]
>
> Arithmetic types ([basic.fundamental]), enumeration types, pointer types, pointer-to-member types ([basic.compound]), std​::​nullptr_­t, and cv-qualified versions of these types are collectively called scalar types.

Of these types, C lacks scoped enumerations, *pointers-to-member*, `std::nullptr_t` and `char8_­t` (`char8_­t` is not yet in C++ either; it will be introduced in the upcoming C++20).

`bool` (`<stdbool.h>`), `wchar_t` (`<stddef.h>`), `char16_­t` and `char32_­t` (`<uchar.h>`) types are only defined in certain standard headers in C.