# Difference between char in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, types, char, integral

I know that C and C++ are different languages.

**Code - C**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%zu",sizeof('a'));
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
4
```

**Code- C++**

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout<<sizeof('a');
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14822074/11862989 in this answer user `Kerrek SB(438k Rep.)` telling about types in C++ nor mentions `char` neither `int` but just integral.

is char in C++ is integral type or strict char type ?

Comment: A character literal in C is an `int`, but in C++, it's a `char`.

Comment: Yes, `char` is an integral type, in both C and C++.    The difference is that a character literal (like `'a'`) has type `char` in C++ (hence size `1`) and type `int` in C (size implementation defined, usually not `1`).

Comment: One good reason for the difference:  C++ has overloaded methods.  For example:  `void method( char c );` and `void method( int n );`.  Calling `method( 'a' );` would call the `int` method if character constants were `int` values in C++.  Because C doesn't have function overloading, that can't happen in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is char in C++ is integral type or strict char type ?

Character types, such as `char`, are integral types in C++.

The type of narrow character constant in C is `int`, while the type of narrow character literal in C++ is `char`.

Comment: what is mean by narrow character can you elaborate ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane `'a'` that is character constant. It has type `int` in ***C*** and type `char` in ***C++***

Comment: `while the type of narrow character literal in C++ is char` what's that  mean ?

Comment: @eerorika can you answer my above 2 comments ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane Narrow character literal is for example `'a'`. This is in contrast to a wide character literal such as `L'a'`. Such literal has a different type - a wide character type. All expressions in C++ have a type. The type of `1` is `int`. The type of `malloc(1)` is `void*`. The type of `'a'` is `char`.

Comment: @eerorika Then what is the narrow character constant ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane `'a'` for example. C uses different nomenclature.

Comment: @eerorika in first comment you said `'a'` is  Narrow character literal now you are saying it is narrow character constant isn't both things are contradicting ?

Comment: @AbhishekMane `in first comment you said 'a' is Narrow character litera` That's because we were talking about C++. `now you are saying it is narrow character constant` Like I said, C uses different nomenclature. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @eerorika means Narrow character literal and Narrow character constant is same thing but just different names in respective languages, right

Comment: @AbhishekMane Yes.

Answer (score 1):

> is char in C++ is integral type or strict char type ?

Usage of [type_traits](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) lets you know the type:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_integral<char>();
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned, In C `'a'` is char constant and treated as an integer.
In C++ it is integral.

Also you can check the difference between char `c = 'a'` and `'a'` in C++ by using RTTI (run time type info) as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;
  
int main()
{

    char c = 'a';
  
    // Get the type info using typeid operator
    const type_info& ti2 = typeid('a');
    const type_info& ti3 = typeid(c);
  

    // Check if both types are same
    if (ti2 != ti3)
        cout << "different type" << endl;
    else
        cout << "same type"<< endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

The output is : `same type`.

However, char `c = 'a'` and `'a'` are NOT same in C.